# работа jar файла 24/7

Tags: java, jar

Вопрос возможно довольно странный, но все же. Суть такая.
Есть jar file бота для телеграмма на java. Бот работает только тогда, когда работает сам jar в фоне. То есть бот работает, пока включен компьютер. Как можно сделать так, чтобы jar работал 24/7 независимо от моего компьютера?? Может хост какой есть? совсем в этом не разбираюсь

Comment: арендуете сервер и запускаете на нём

Comment: @komdosh как это сделать ???? и есть ли бесплатный способ??

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov а вы готовы предоставить мне свой компьютер бесплатно для работы моего бота 24/7? Уверен, что нет.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev знаю, что то, о чем я спросил, возможно на Python. Вопрос был для людей, которые знают, что ответить

Comment: В смысле на Python возможно? В любом случае нужна работающая машина, если не ваша, то скорее всего нужен удалённый сервер, но как правильно заметил Сергей, вряд ли есть бесплатные решения, а если и есть то на время или с большим списком ограничений.

Comment: Бред какой-то, нет и быть не может бесплатных серверов, даже в качестве рекламы. Любой ДЦ предлагая пробный период, берёт с вас платёжные денные, где блокирует определённую сумму - может даже один цент. Но данный вид блокировки суммы на карте, позволяет в дальнейшем списать сумму расходов без вашего участия с вашего счёта.  БЕСПЛАТНЫЙ СЫР В МЫШЕЛОВКЕ.